# How to SUM() range of cell values as text with "$" character?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I want to `SUM` the values in a range of rows.
The values are as text because these contain character `$`. It doesn't work simply with `SUM` so I tried to take the `$` character away using `ÀRRAYFORMULA` together with `SUBSTITUTE`, or just `SUBSTITUTE` and then `SUM` like this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUM(E2:E13),"$ ","")
```

and this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SUM(E2:E13),"$ ",""))
```

But the result is always `0`. Is there a way to do this?
I know that if the cells are formatted as number a simple `SUM` will work but on my main file the output of those values come with `$` character so I need to find a way to take out the `$` and then sum in 1 formula.

Here is my test file:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YYLARGtXXIH1rDTa42hQtB0W-XXk4X4He7lLgev91Tc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up using:

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(B2:B13,"$ ",""))))
```

It is important to use `VALUE` to make the array go from text to number after `$` is taken out by `SUBSTITUTE`. This is why the order is important:

`SUBSTITUTE`-> `VALUE`-> `ARRAYFORMULA` -> `SUM`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=arrayformula(sum(value(iferror(regexreplace(B2:B,"^\$\ ",),))))
```

Comment: That works. But I will use this instead for simplicity's sake: `=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(B2:B13,"$ ",""))))`. Basically I just needed `VALUE`for this to work. You replaced `SUBSTITUTE` with `REGEXREPLACE` any reason why? Also I was trying to figure out how to use `REGEX` expressions before posting this but couldn't figure out how to use it or what it is actually. Thank you for your help.